# NVD - JSON to CSV with Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to download the NVD CVE. Here is my pythoncode:

```
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds#JSON_FEED')
for filename in re.findall("nvdcve-1.0-[0-9]*\.json\.zip",r.text):
    print(filename)
    r_file = requests.get("https://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/" + filename, stream=True)
    with open("nvd/" + filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r_file:
            f.write(chunk)
```

Now I want to write all JSON-files ina  csv-file with this format:

```
Name, Value, Description, ..., ...  
Name, Value, Description, ..., ...
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should get you started, giving you two columns, `ID,`VendorName`,`Description`and`VendorValues`:

```
import requests
import re
import zipfile
import io
import json
import csv

with open("nvdcve-1.0-2017.json") as f_json:
r = requests.get('https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds#JSON_FEED')

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['ID', 'VendorName', 'Description', 'VersionValues'])

    for filename in re.findall("nvdcve-1.0-[0-9]*\.json\.zip", r.text):
        print("Downloading {}".format(filename))
        r_zip_file = requests.get("https://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/" + filename, stream=True)
        zip_file_bytes = io.BytesIO()

        for chunk in r_zip_file:
            zip_file_bytes.write(chunk)

        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_bytes)

        for json_filename in zip_file.namelist():
            print("Extracting {}".format(json_filename))
            json_raw = zip_file.read(json_filename).decode('utf-8')
            json_data = json.loads(json_raw)

            for entry in json_data['CVE_Items']:
                try:
                    vendor_name = entry['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['vendor_name']
                except IndexError:
                    vendor_name = "unknown"

                try:
                    url = entry['cve']['references']['reference_data'][0]['url']
                except IndexError:
                    url = ''

                try:
                    vv = []

                    for pd in entry['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['product']['product_data']:
                        for vd in pd['version']['version_data']:
                            vv.append(vd['version_value'])

                    version_values = '/'.join(vv)
                except IndexError:
                    version_values = ''

                csv_output.writerow([
                    entry['cve']['CVE_data_meta']['ID'],
                    url,
                    vendor_name,
                    entry['cve']['description']['description_data'][0]['value'],
                    version_values])
```

This downloads the zipfile into memory. It then extracts all files one at a time into memory and converts the json into a Python datas structure using `json.loads()`. For each entry in `CVE_Items` it then extracts a couple of the fields and writes them to a CSV file.

As the JSON data is highly structured, you will need to consider how you would want to represent all of the fields in a CSV file. Currently it extras two "useful" fields and stores those.

Alternatively instead of making your own CSV you could work with Pandas:

```
df = pd.read_json(json_raw)
df.to_csv(f_output)
```

Remove the `csv_output` lines. This though would need some extra work to decide on how it should be formatted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tryed this with pandas, but I get this format: "0,"{'cve': {'data_type': 'CVE', 'data_format': ...". Your first solution is better because I have customization options. 
I had a similar solution like yours but I did a mistake with the keywords in the for-loop.

Comment: Just add `ID` to the header and then add a new first entry to the list in `csv_output.writerow()`. I have updated the script to show this. I agree this approach is quite flexible depending on what you are trying to extract.

Comment: If I use this code: entry['cve']['references']['reference_data'][0]['url'] I get the error "list index out of range"

Comment: The code is correct, but not all entries have a url, so you would need to add another `try` `except` block.

Comment: you are right. For the versionnumber: version_value = entry['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['product']['product_data'][0]['version']['version_data'][0]['version_value']

Now it works with try-catch

Comment: Only one question: How can I get the number of values for example to list all version_values? (len(entry['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['product']['product_data'][0]['version']['version_data'])) ist not working

Comment: You probably need the `len()` of `product_data`

Comment: print (len(entry['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['product']['product_data'])) is not working

Comment: For me it gave many results and then stopped. I'm guessing not all have `vendor_data`, so again a `try` `except` block is needed.

Comment: Yes, but after I have to append it to the row. But when I am using it for more then one reference I get more then one row depending on counter

Comment: You need to decide whether to combine all possible entries into a single CSV cell (e.g. v1, v2, v3 or v1\nv2\nv3). Or you will need to reserve multiple columns e.g. `v1` `v2` `v3`.

Comment: I want this format: ID, vendor_name, description, reference1/reference2/reference3